# QML MenuItem trigger by Enter and keyboard events forwarding don't work

Tags: qt, qml

Here I have a minimal example:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2


Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Component.onCompleted: {
        menu.open();
    }

    Menu {
        id: menu

        Keys.onPressed: {
            console.log("pressed")
        }

        MenuItem {
            text: "test"
            Keys.forwardTo: [menu]
            focus: highlighted
            onTriggered: {
                console.log("triggered 1")
            }
        }
        MenuItem {
            text: "test2"
            focus: highlighted
            Keys.forwardTo: [menu]
            onTriggered: {
                console.log("triggered 2")
            }
        }
        MenuItem {
            text: "test3"
            focus: highlighted
            Keys.forwardTo: [menu]
            onTriggered: {
                console.log("triggered 3")
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Navigating through Menu Items with keyboard works as expected. But triggering with Enter key doesn't work. Also as a workaround I tried to forward key events to the parent menu item, and it didn't work as well.

The only way to fix it I see right now: place `Keys.onReturnPressed` to every MenuItem and make it call triggered() signal. But it feels wrong.

Is it a bug of Qt?
What is a right workaround for it?

I'm using Qt 5.10.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Menu` is not `Item`, so it could not set into `Keys.forwardTo`.
The navigation of `Menu` via the `Forward/Backward` key is enabled by default, `Keys.forwardTo` is not necessary.

Why Enter key does not work because to select the `MenuItem` is using `Space` key not the `Enter` key. `[↑]` and `[↓]` is for `Navigation(focus)` and `[Space]` is for `Selection`

I think if you want to listen the `[Enter]` key for the `Selection`, add `Keys.onReturnPressed: triggered();` is the right way.

**Update:**

The `[Enter]` key was worked in Qt 5.6 (verified). check the [source](https://github.com/qt/qtquickcontrols/blob/25d6bd04611837cbc81f6a1247c3008f08ed9f9d/src/controls/Private/MenuContentItem.qml) code. But looks like it is removed in the current version.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think that every platform has adopted selection of menu items by [enter] key. I just double checked several apps, both are working [Space] and [Enrer] . It's strange that Qt follows a different way.

Comment: @IvanFateev BTW, Which Qt version you using.

Comment: I'm using 5.10.1, forgot to mention it

Comment: I believe that's because MenuItem inherits a Button, which can be triggered only by the Space key

Comment: If you really need that feature you can use the old version(5.6)...have a look I updated.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried almost everything and finally found this. I'm using Qt 5.4.2 on Win7. This was working for me: `Keys.onReturnPressed: buttonId.clicked()`